# Getting empty values, while parsing XML using Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have an XML file like the following. I am loading the XML using `XMLLOader`. It is working fine. But, while fetching the values it is giving empty values:

```
<mfh>
    <f></f>
    <sn>***</sn>
    <st>****</st>
    <vnr>****</vnr>
    <cb>***</cb>
</mfh>
<md>
    <nei>
        <ne>***</ne>
        <k>***</k>
        <n>***</n>
    </nei>
    <mi>
        <mts>**</mts>
        <g>**</g>
        <mv>
            <m>***</m>
        </mv>
    </mi>
   .....
   .....
</md>
```

My Pig script is as follows:

```
REGISTER '/usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar'
a = load '/user/root/sample.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('mfh') as (doc:chararray);
dump input_xml;
b = foreach input_xml generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'<mfh>\\s*<ffv>(.*)</ffv>\\s*</mfh'));
dump required_tags;
```

The output of the script is as follows:

It is not givning any errors, but the output is (). I have updated the XML file and I want to parse all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

To print the value of 'ffv' attribute as per your example:

```
 required_tags = foreach input_xml generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'<mfh>\\s+<ffv>(.*)</ffv>.*'));
```

To print all the values of ffv,sn,st,vn,cbt:

```
   required_tags = foreach input_xml generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'<mfh>\\s+<ffv>(.*)</ffv>\\s+<sn>(.*)</sn>\\s+<st>(.*)</st>\\s+<vn>(.*)</vn>\\s+<cbt>(.*)</cbt>\\s+</mfh>'));
```

Comment: second one is working to print all the values,but first one is not working to get single value

Comment: For me its working fine. can you paste the dump of input_xml?

Comment: the above mentioned xml is not complete xml file,it has so many other tags.when i copy the above into separate xml,then i am able to fetch the values using your second solution.But while i am trying to fetch from full xml it's not working.

Comment: Generally parsing a xml file using Regex is not at all recommended. One workaround will be you can convert your xml file to json using any online convertor and load the json file using elephantbird loader. This will give much flexible for retrieving all the fields in key/value pairs. I am not saying this is the best solution but compare to writing a complex regex for xml this will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

required_tags = foreach input_xml generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(doc,'\s*(.*)\s*(.*)\s*(.*)\s*(.*)\s*(.*)')) AS (ffv,sn,st,vn,cbt);
dump required_tags;